# Server only reachable locally

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding

Hi I wonder if anyone can try to point me in the right direction...

I have a simple web server. It works fine but now that I'm setting it up to run in the cloud I am having trouble connecting to it from outside the machine on which it is running. Details:

- I'm running on an Amazon Lightsail Ubuntu instance
- The server is serving HTTPS at port 8443
- I used `iptables` to

  - accept all on port 8443
  - accept all on port 443
  - forward from port 443 to port 8443
- I have configured the Amazon Lightsail settings to open port 443 via the AWS console

Now..

- I can verify that the server is running using `wget https://0.0.0.0:8443 --no-check-certificate` from the lightsail instance, which completes successfully and downloads a web page
- However this fails: `wget https://<amazon lightsail instance external static IP>:8443 --no-check-certificate` with `Connection refused`
- As does `wget https://<amazon lightsail instance external static IP>:443 --no-check-certificate`

What is preventing external TCP connections to my server?

iptables setup:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8443

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Also UFW is not running

```
> sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

[Edit] After opening port 8443 to the world using the AWS console, I am able to connect remotely using `wget https://<external ip>:8443`, so it appears everything is working except foe port forwarding in `iptables`

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Sorry but your iptables doesn't show anything in forward...

Comment: Ah right, I have in fact attempted to do a port redirect, not a forward, using this line

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get everything working the way I want:

Accept incoming TCP connections on ports 443 and 8443

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
```

Redirect port 8443 to 443

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

Save changes to iptables

```
sudo iptables-save
```